# Поиск JavaScript отрабатывающего на данном элементе

Tags: javascript

В проекте есть prototype, jquery, ну и просто JS. Есть всплывающий календарь, его позиция задаётся где-то динамически.
Есть ли возможность безошибочно определить в каком именно JS меняются параметры?
Не хочется наугад изменить, и в не подозреваемом месте вылезет кака.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фреймворки оперируют объектами  DOM-модели, используя в качестве "адресов" элементов HTML, id, name, class. С помощью firebug или чего-нибудь подобного найдите какие идентификаторы использует блок календаря. Далее шерстите по поиску данные идентификаторы, любое управление завязано на них, так, что рано или поздно найдете.

Comment: Ну не только по id, name и class, например по номеру элемента, или по отношению к предкам.  
Думал более существенный совет будет по методу поиска. Значит все очень скучно с поиском.  
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ну всплывающий календарь на Jquery с селектором в котором описывается отношение к предкам, по-моему диковато и сложно. А вообще в таких ситуациях нужен индивидуальный опыт, я вот например смогу определить по внешнему виду на вскидку автокомплит от Jquery Autocomplete и Jquery UI Autocomplete, потому, что имел с ними дело. А по календарю зайдите на jquery autocomplete theme roller посмотрите там имеющиеся календари и сравните с прототайповскими может поможет и будет не так скучно)). Чистый js вряд ли юзался, так уже включено две библиотеки.

Comment: Вы правы, написано было на прототайпе, и нашел откуда ноги растут по class, но календарь не стандартный, пришлось в функции лесть. Но да, согласен, главное найти отправную точку, а тут она начиналась с элемента class.

Answer (score 0):

есть такое дополнение в firefox - fireQuery. Оно показывает какие обработчики навешаны на элемент